# Meteor search engine optimization

Tags: javascript, meteor, seo

Following this blog [post](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteor-and-seo) I used this [package](https://github.com/DerMambo/ms-seo) to setup my SEO. While the page title shows up correctly on the title bar, when I `curl http://localhost:3000/about -4` into the webpage I don't see any meta tags. I am setting up everything exactly the same as the document as below:

```
Router.route('/about', {
  'name': 'About',

  'action': function() {
    this.render('About', {
      to: 'content'
    });
  },

  'onAfterAction': function() {
    if (!Meteor.isClient) {
      return;
    }

    SEO.set({
      title: "My website",
      meta: {
        'description': "testing."
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SEO` package modifies the tags on-browser. This means it's if you load it up in your browser.

To view it using curl make sure you have the `spiderable` package in, phantomjs installed and view your route using `curl http://localhost:3000/about?_escaped_fragment_=#`

This will force it to be rendered using phantomjs using the spiderable package as per the [AJAX web crawling spec](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

Comment: Thank you. I assume Google bot does something similar to `curl`. Does it mean that `SEO` package is meant to be used along with `spiderable` package? What is the real purpose?

Comment: @MaximusS Meteor is a one-page app framework so spiderable will use phantomjs to render those out as fully body html pages. It depends more on the crawler, Google is able to parse javascript so it may not be necessary for them. It is necessary if you want the full body as html by directly retrieving it using `curl` or `wget` though. I'm not very well aware with the search engine crawlers capabilities well enough to give a definite answer. There is that AJAX crawling spec which basically outlines that it can help if you do give full body html back if it is requested using the `escaped_fragment`

Comment: So you need to use `spiderable` package to render content inside `body` tags, and `ms-seo` package to set `meta` tags dynamically.

Comment: @MaximusS Your app will do this in the browser even if you don't use spiderable. View your browser's DOM when you visit a page instead of its source using wget/curl. It should contain the tags. Spiderable just extends this to work with `curl` and `wget` if you add the escaped_fragment. Some crawlers may also not have the technical ability to act as a headless browser.

Answer (score -1):

`curl` doesn't run JS. So meteor kind of things doesn't work. You need server side rendering. Check [this blog](https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-server-sider-rendering-for-seo-purpose.html).

Comment: isn't that the purpose of the package though? Inserting metadata so that the metadata is injected.. But now that I think about it, I think I could be misunderstanding. Do you know what exactly does the package in the original question does then?

Comment: Yeah it is for SEO purpose. But it only works with phantomjs (or smth like that) because it doesn't render on server.

Comment: You need to do `curl http://localhost:3000/about?_escaped_fragment_=# -4` to check correctly.